# How can i make all the gameobjects to flash in turn?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I mean like in airplane landing lights effect. The first object will be color in red then it will turn to green and the next one will be red then green and the next one red and so on in a loop. Like showing path or route. Starting with red then after 0.5 seconds start with green. I think. The effect is to show/light a way/path.

Inside Update

```
void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine(LightsEffect());
}
```

Then

```
IEnumerator LightsEffect()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
    {
        objects[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
    {
        objects[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f); 
}
```

But this color them all once in green.

Comment: I would definetly not call the `StartCoroutine` every frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it :

```
public List<GameObject> objects ;
public float delay = 0.1f;
private Renderer[] renderers;
private float lastChangeTime;
private int greenIndex = 0;

void Awake()
{
    // Retrieve the renderer of each object and init to red color
    renderers = new Renderer[objects.Count];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < renderers.Length ; i++ )
    {
        renderers[i] = objects[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderers[i].material.color = Color.red;
    }

    // Set green color to the first one
    greenIndex = 0;
    renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
}

void Update()
{
    // Change color each `delay` seconds
    if( Time.time > lastChangeTime + delay )
    {
        lastChangeTime = Time.time;

        // Set color of the last renderer to red
        // and the color of the current one to green
        renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.red;
        greenIndex = ( greenIndex + 1 ) % renderers.Length;
        renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep this as a coroutine (not my preference, but alternative to Hellium's answer), you need to understand that a coroutine is not a loop (that last `yield` doesn't help anything: as soon as it is done, no other code runs and the method terminates).

So we'll start with your original coroutine method and *make* it a loop:

```
IEnumerator LightsEffect()
{
    while(true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            objects[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            objects[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f); 
    }
}
```

Now, since this will never actually terminate, we only need to start the coroutine once:

```
void Awake()
{
    StartCoroutine(LightsEffect());
}
```

We'd probably also want to set up logic to clean things up when we're done making the lights blink, but this is sufficient for now.